# LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle with ionic app

Tags: authentication, ionic-framework, symfony, fosrestbundle, lexikjwtauthbundle

I have seen many post on this subject, but i can't make a correct request, regardless all of my tests.
I hope anyone could help me on this.

My current configuration : 
I work with wamp - apache 2.4.9 -- php 5.5.12
I work with symfony3

i add all rewrite rules in my vhost :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.)
RewriteRule . - [e=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
```

On backend, my security.yml is :

```
firewalls:

        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        api_doc:
            pattern: ^/api/doc
            anonymous: true

        api_login:
            pattern:  ^/api/login
            provider: fos_userbundle
            stateless: true
            anonymous: true
            form_login:
                check_path:     /api/login_check
                require_previous_session: false
                success_handler:          lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
                failure_handler:          lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure

        api:
            pattern:   ^/api
            stateless: true
            provider: fos_userbundle
            lexik_jwt:
                authorization_header:
                    enabled: true
                    prefix:  Bearer
                query_parameter:
                    enabled: true
                    name:    Bearer
                throw_exceptions:        true
                create_entry_point:      true
```

Configuration  of fosuserbundle :

```
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: UserBundle\Entity\User
    group:
        group_class: UserBundle\Entity\Group
        form:
            type: UserBundle\Form\Type\GroupFormType
    profile:
        form:
            type: UserBundle\Form\Type\ProfileFormType
```

And side of client, i use ionic with angular js, and i try to get the token with :

```
 var loginData = {
                username: this.login.username,
                password: this.login.password
            };

            console.debug(loginData);

            $http({
                url: 'http://app.local/app_dev.php/api/login_check',
                method: 'POST',
                data: loginData,
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'},
                ignoreAuthModule: true
            })
                .success(function (data) {
                    console.log("Success -- login ok with ".data);
                    $scope.token = data;
                })
                .error(function (data) {
                    console.log("ERROR -- login fail with ", data);
                    $scope.token = data;
                });
```

that's always return me 'bad credentials'

But my test with curl send me a token

```
curl -X POST http://app.local/api/login_check -d _username=username -d _password=pass
```

I have test to prefix _ my login data, change configuration

If anyone have an idea ??

---

EDIT :

Maybe i have found my problem.

This request curl work fine :

```
curl -X POST http://app.local/api/login_check -d _username=username -d _password=pass
```

But this one doesn't work :

```
 curl -X POST http://app.local/app_dev.php/api/login_check -d '{"username": "user", "password": "pass"}'
```

I search one solution for solve it, but i guess angular http method cannot send two parameters

---

EDIT 2 :
This request works fine :

```
curl -X POST http://app.local/app_dev.php/api/login_check -d '{"_username": "user", "_password": "pass"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json"
```

I search a solution for copy this request with angular http object

---

EDIT 3 :

I make my angular request like this :

```
var loginData = {
                _username: this.login.username,
                _password: this.login.password
            };
            $http({
                url: 'http://app.local/app_dev.php/api/login_check',
                method: 'POST',
                data: loginData,
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
            })
                .success(function (data) {
                    console.log("Success -- login ok with ".data);
                })
                .error(function (error) {
                    console.log("ERROR -- login fail with ", error);
                });
```

And my javascript console print an error :

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://app.local/app_dev.php/api/login_check. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 404
```

---

EDIT 4 :

I ddin't found the solution ...

It seems CORS request is the problem. i try do reset all headers in my mobile app, nothing has changed.
I try to install nelmioCorsBundle for authorize OPTIONS headers and control my configuration, nothing has changed

I have installed the sandbox (https://github.com/slashfan/LexikJWTAuthenticationBundleSandbox) and i have exactly the same problem.

When i try to execute curl request, i can get my token. When i use angular/ionic app, i have the error : 
https://github.com/slashfan/LexikJWTAuthenticationBundleSandbox

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://app.local/app_dev.php/api/login_check. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values '*, http://localhost:8100', but only one is allowed. Origin 'http://localhost:8100' is therefore not allowed access.
```

If anyone have a new idea ?? i don't know what i can test now :s

PS : which version of angular is working with demo app in the LexikJWTAuthenticationBundleSandbox ?

Comment: `http://app.local` can't work out of your local machine (as when you run it through curl). If you run the curl request from another machine, it will not work too. You need a __valid__ domain and deploy your API in production, then use this valid domain as endpoint, e.g. `http://yourrealdomain.com/api/login_check`

Comment: After that you bought the domain, let me know if you need some resources helping to configure it.

Comment: Ok, i have deployed my backend on server, and real domain, but for my first tests, nothing has changed. I have learn so much about angular/CORS/REST these last days, so i continue my test on production and repeat them

Answer (score 0):

In the first (working) request you are using `_username` as field with value "username" and `_password` as field with value "pass".

In the second you are using `username` (instead of `_username`) as field with value "user" and `password` (instead of `_password`) as field with value "pass".

Change your second request to:

```
curl -X POST http://app.local/app_dev.php/api/login_check -d '{"_username": "username", "_password": "pass"}'
```

And it should work.

**EDIT**

Add the option `-H "Content-Type: application/json`, that gives:

```
curl -X POST http://app.local/app_dev.php/api/login_check  -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"_username": "username", "_password": "pass"}'
```

And it should work!

**EDIT**

It seems to be a CORS related issue.
Try to add the following in your angular application, before doing the POST request:

```
app.config(function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common = {};
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post = {};
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.put = {};
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.patch = {};
});
```

Where app is your angular module (i.e. `var app = angular.module(...)`).

Comment: Sorry, its my mistake with many copy/paste ....
I try both, and the bundle accept syntax with prefix "_" but not the array. so `curl -X POST http://app.local/app_dev.php/api/login_check -d '{"_username": "username", "_password": "pass"}'` doesn't work :s

Comment: Yes this curl request works fine =) But when i use `headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8; application/json'}` on my angular http request, this doesn't work - what i did wrong ?

Comment: You are trying to set multiple content types, that doesn't make sense.
Simply use `headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }`

Comment: Thx @chalasr. Ok, so request curl with json content type is okay, but when i try to make angular http post request with this params, i have a XMLHttpRequest error -- i edit my post

Comment: Please Look at my edit. Also, if you are testing the app on a mobile device, you cannot use `http://app.local`, you need a server with a valid domain accessible from every other platform.To test it, try to simply execute your angular code in a browser way.

Comment: Thx for your help and your patience. I have upload backend on my server,  and i have same situation, curl request is OK, and http method return me an error, even with your header params :s i continue to search a solution

Comment: I have edited my post, i continue to search a working solution